# Is there a form-filling application or Macro that can work on MS Word documents?

Tags: forms, microsoft-word

When I do job applications online, I use Lastpass to do the dumb stuff like enter my name.

Is there any way I can do this for MS Word based forms? It wouldn't have to be that smart, just know that when it sees 'name' it should put my name next to it, and so on.